# How to add an HTML class to a Django form's help_text?

Tags: python, django

I have a simple form

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    fieldname = forms.CharField(help_text="Some help text")
```

I can then display this form with django's handy `{{ form.as_ul }}` if I like, now I need to stylise the help_text and I have no idea how.  Django doesn't appear to wrap that string in anything that will let my CSS get to it so at the moment, I've restored to:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    fieldname = forms.CharField(help_text='<div class="helptext">Some help text</div>')
```

Which I *know* is wrong so I'm looking here for better advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's only that much you can customize in UI from form options.  The more flexible way to approach a problem is to create your own form template then and reuse it instead of `{{ form.as_something }}`.  Read these topics from Django documentation:

- [Customizing form templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

This worked very well when I needed significantly customized form marks yet keeping it DRY.

Comment: Agreed. form.as_* is for quick prototyping only; real form layout requires doing it in the template. Not necessarily field-by-field; in most cases I just loop through the fields and present each one with the same HTML.

Answer (score 14):

A more convenient way to do this is to:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
```

and then:

```
field = models.TextField(help_text=mark_safe("some<br>html"))
```

Comment: Nit: I prefer `format_html('<p class="errornote">{}</p>', 'Your fancy warning')` since your text get html-escaped automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no other way, otherwise there probably wouldn't be a need for this ticket: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8426.

You could apply the patch that is provided there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know since this was available but this works for me in the template :

```
{{ field|add_label_class:'class-name' }}
```